# Sending mail to multiple recipient

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have a simple interface that looks like below:

[image]

It's pretty self-explanatory and I can enter my recipient email and it will pass the value to a function.

My javascript function(when send button invoked):

```
<script>
    //function to insert content of email to table

    function sendmessage(){

        var recipient = document.getElementById("recipient").value;    
        var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;    
        var content=document.getElementById("content").value;    

        $.ajax({    
            url: 'sendemail.jsp',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                recipient:recipient,
                subject:subject,
                content:content    
            },    
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Successfully send email");
            },
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });    
    } 
</script>    

<body>    
To:<input type="text" style="font-size: 10pt;" size="30" id="recipient"  ><br><br>    
Subject:<input type="text" style="font-size: 10pt" size="70" id="subject" ><br><br>  
Content:<br><textarea cols="100"  rows="10" id="content"  style="font-size: 13pt;">
    <%=files%>:   <%=url%>
</textarea><br>  
<div class="Send">
    <button type="button" onclick="sendmessage()"> Send </button>
</div>
```

It passes to my sendemail.jsp(snippet):

```
<%   
    String recipient=request.getParameter("recipient");
    String subject=request.getParameter("subject");
    String content=request.getParameter("content");

    fileFacade.sendEmail(recipient,subject,content);  
%>
```

And my email function:

```
public void sendEmail(String recipient,String subject,String content) {
        try {    
            final String fromEmail = "xxxxx@gmail.com"; //requires valid gmail id
            final String password = "xxxx"; // correct password for gmail id   
            System.out.println("Please Wait, sending email...");

            /*Setup mail server */
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); //TLS Port
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS

            //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);    
            session.setDebug(true);

            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient));
            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject(subject);

            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText(content);

            try {
                Transport.send(message);
            } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                addressException.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }    
    }
```

My code above works for a single recipient and now I would like to allow it to send to multiple recipient like in the format of shown in the screenshot above. I do not want to create a CC column for reasons.

How do I  pass multiple values of emails to multiple recipients in the way I want?

Comment: sure. add them all in the same input box, separated by a ;, use String split to split the addresses, and perform the send for all of them.

Comment: So if i'm sending to 3 recipients, I am calling the function three times?

Comment: No. You pass the three recipients as one String. You split it in the method, and execute it's logic three times, but you only call it once. You also may want to update your code a bit. <br> is very archaic. <br /> is the updated equivalent. Also: don't put code in your jsp file, use your servlets for those. If you post a next question, please don't keep that many white lines in it. They just give more to scroll though. they don't add anything to your code nor question.

Comment: Ok noted. You said `<br/>` instead of <br> ,?

Comment: yup. it's been quite some years that all tags can be closed within, and should be closed. so <a>click me</a> is valid, <br /> is valid <br> 'll work but should be avoided

Comment: Why do people say it's fine writing code in jsp file as in backend code? I know servlet would be a better choice.

Comment: who said it's fine to write code in jsp files? it'll work, sure, but it'll create messy code that 'll be very difficult to maintain. It's like saying: "You can wear your pants on your head, so you should". sure, 't won't kill you, but it'll look ridiculous. you should NOT have java code in your jsp file, the jsp file is meant for UI purposes, not business logic.

Comment: Hi Daredevil. @Mark has removed some homemade "tags" from a few of your question titles. This is correct [as per this canonical Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028/why-is-removing-tags-from-the-title-suggested-so-often/). Going forward, please phrase your titles in a way that does not add extra tags - the tag system handles these just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use "split".  Just use:

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can split your recipient email list based on `,` and then iterate through each email and send to each. as:

**UPDATE**: You dont need to call `send` method in a loop. just adding recipeints multiple time will send email to all at once.

```
String[] receipentList = recipient.split(",");
for (String to : receipentList) {
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
}
try {
      Transport.send(message);
} catch (AddressException addressException) {
      addressException.printStackTrace();
}
```

Full Code:

```
public void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String content) {
        try {
            final String fromEmail = "xxxxx@gmail.com"; //requires valid gmail id
            final String password = "xxxx"; // correct password for gmail id
            System.out.println("Please Wait, sending email...");
            /*Setup mail server */
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); //TLS Port
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS
            //create Authenticator object to pass in Session.getInstance argument
            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            session.setDebug(true);
            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject(subject);
            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText(content);
            String[] receipentList = recipient.split(",");
            for (String to : receipentList) {
                 message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new 
                  InternetAddress(to));
            }
            try {
                 Transport.send(message);
            } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                  addressException.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: So this means I can send the email to either one recipient or two or more right/

Comment: But I am calling the function the number of times I set the recipient list, isn't this slow?

Comment: @Daredevil you don't call the method (not function) that many times. You perform the Send that many times

Comment: @Mustahsan what do you mean "unless it is separated by commas"? don't you mean "as long"?

Comment: you are not calling whole method. you are just calling the `send` function with every field same just recipient changed. so it will be slow but not that much, just fractions of second

Comment: @Stultuske yes my bad i meant as long

Comment: Regarding my question, I shall use `;` instead of comma because it's how actual email separator works

Comment: yes then you can split your string based on `;` just a minor change

Comment: @Daredevil "actual email separator", that depends on the mailing client/tool you use. functionality wise, you could just as easy use the String "[FancyMailSeparator]" as separtator

Comment: @Daredevil i updated my answer with some performance improvements.

Comment: I meant that you can use that entire String as separator. it all depends on how you write your code. I've seen a mail client once that used @@ as separator between their addresses, since each email address can contain maximal one @, so @@ can't be part of a valid email address. Looks a bit odd, but next to that, works just as it should