# How to retrieve data if stored as object?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

I am using ajax to pass data to servlet. From what I know the standard way usually goes like this:

```
$.ajax({

               url: 'page.jsp',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {

                     id:value,
                     name:value2

               },

               success: function (data) {
                   alert("Successfully initiated email to queue");
               },
               error: function (request, error) {
                   alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(error));
               }
           });
```

And in the jsp page, one would retrieve the data like this:

```
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
```

This would work no doubt. Now what if I want to store the data as objects. Like this in my JavaScript:

```
 var data;

     if(condition){

       data={
                'recipient': recipient,
                'subject': subject,
                'content': content,
                'id':"<%=id%>",
                'hash':"<%=hash%>",
                'multiemail':"no"

            }

    }else{

          data= {
                'recipient': recipient,
                'subject': subject,
                'content': content,
                'arrayList':<%=array%>,
                'multiemail':"yes"

            }

    }
  $.ajax({

               url: 'page.jsp',
               type: 'POST',
               data: {

                     info:data

               },

               success: function (data) {
                   alert("Successfully initiated email to queue");
               },
               error: function (request, error) {
                   alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(error));
               }
           });
```

Then, I used the same way:

```
 String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");
```

And this would returns null value. How do I exactly retrieve the data value I want from the object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179986/how-to-retrieve-data-from-json-file-using-jquery-and-ajax check if you can find anything similar here

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar: He mentions `servlet`. He's trying to get the JSON value in Java

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar No that's not what i was looking for.

Comment: Don't have time to write full reply but you should google about `java jackson` for how to deal with JSON data (the serialized form of js objects) and read this answer for how to get that data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525982/getting-request-payload-from-post-request-in-java-servlet

Comment: Based on the link you gave,it tells me to use `request.getreader`. But how exactly to I get the "particular" data in the object?

Comment: I pointed out [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55467579/472495) that the community has removed home-made tags from your titles. Volunteer editors do not want to keep doing so, as they are busy enough as it is. **Please refrain from adding tags to your titles**. A canonical meta discussion is available on request.

Answer (score 0):

When you used the following line of code `String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");`
It looks for a recipient key in data in

```
           $.ajax({
           url: 'page.jsp',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {

                 info:data

           }
```

but hardluck there is no recipient, there is only **info** key in your ajax.
Therefore you can use getParameter("info") to get the **data**. Now you have your data.

Refer the following code

```
$.ajax({
           url: 'page.jsp',
           type: 'POST',
           data: data
```

I think now you can use `String recipient = request.getParameter("recipient");`

Comment: But I want to get a particular data in `info` such as `recipient`,is this possible?

Comment: yeah it's possible, you can use getAttribute() method instead of getParameter()

Comment: so how would the code look like? Please provide substantial explanation

Comment: Now I edited the answer with a new code segment, please look at it and update me if there happens anything

Comment: it doesn't work because i know that's not how it works

Comment: No way, I just run the code and I got the exact output

Comment: You're saying i have to getparameter for `info` and then just use the same way to get parameter for `recipient`?

Comment: No no not like that, did you see the last code segement I added. There I don't use info. Please take a look at it. 
$.ajax({
           url: 'page.jsp',
           type: 'POST',
           data: data
If you do it like this you can use getparameter for recipient.

Comment: I just followed your answer above

Comment: Nothing happened ?

Comment: Nothing happen that is why

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameter("recipient");` will look for recipient key in your data. But your key here is `info` not `recipient` (which is part of info). To access recipient, you have to first parse received JSON (`request.getParameter("info")`) using any JSON parsing library and then access recipient from the parsed JSON object.

In your ajax, pass your data in json format

$.ajax({

```
           url: 'page.jsp',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'JSON',
           data: {
                 info:data
           },

           success: function (data) {
               alert("Successfully initiated email to queue");
           },
           error: function (request, error) {
               alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(error));
           }
       });
```

In your servlet side, parse json like this :

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

String json = request.getParameter("info");

JsonElement jsonTree = parser.parse(json);
String recipientjsonTree.get("recipient");
```

`JsonParser` is part of GSON library.

Comment: Yes. it will surely work if your `info` is in proper JSON format

Comment: Wait let me test

Comment: ` JsonParser parser=new JsonParser();` gives a error, i need to enter something in bracket

Comment: I am using jsp acting as my servlet. hope that's fine

Comment: If you face any parsing-related exception, then your `info` object is incorrect json format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192407/discussion-between-abhijeet-and-daredevil).